# How to tell the code to choose between two variables and make them equal?

Tags: c#, css, selenium, xpath

I'm working on a unit test, the test platform is a dynamic website and so CSS Selector and xpath change very often. So I thought to myself maybe I can use both CSS and xpath to retrieve the same text.

The main issue I face right now is how to tell the code to equal the two retrieved strings, like that it does not matter if the xpath fails the CSS Selector will still work and vice versa.

Here is a simple code

```
string text1 = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpathtext")).Text;
string text2 = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("csstext")).Text;
text1 = text2;
//then use text1 or text2
```

is there any clean and neat way of doing it?

Comment: Your question is **extremely** unclear.  But it sounds like you're looking for an `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IWebElement element1 = driver.FindElementIfExists(By.XPath("xpathtext"));
IWebElement element2 = driver.FindElementIfExists(By.CssSelector("csstext"));

string value = (element1 != null ? element1.Text : (element2 != null ? element2.Text : null));
```

It relies on the FindElementIfExists extension method. It's just a matter of creating this class in your project:

```
public static class WebDriverExtensions
{        
    public static IWebElement FindElementIfExists(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
    {
        IWebElement result = null;

        try
        {
            result = driver.FindElement(by);
        }
        catch { }

        return result;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily shorter or cleaner but maybe a bit more versatile is leveraging LINQ. Instead of `FindElement` I use [`FindElements`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebElement_FindElements.htm) because the latter is better used for case where you plan on NOT finding elements as it will return an empty list instead of throwing an exception:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");

// setup an array with all needed
// By instances, you can mix and match
var byList = new [] { 
    By.CssSelector(".categories"),
    By.XPath("//body/noscript"),
    By.Id("sidebar"),
    By.ClassName("module")
};

// do a SelectMany and use FindElements
// instead of FindElement
// take the first
var match = (from byItem in byList 
             from elements in driver.FindElements(byItem)
             select elements).FirstOrDefault();

// if we have a null none of the 
// By operators did return an element
if (match != null)
{
    // do what ever you need to do if match is not null
} 
else 
{
    // none of your search terms was found
}
```

Comment: alright, thanks a lot you helped me so much. I'll definitely implement your code in my work.